# My axes won't show up

Tags: c#, opengl, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a class drawing a 3D indicator such as this one : [image]

indicating the current rotation of the camera by drawing each axis at every frame as if it was in 3D.

However, when my code runs I just can't see anything being drawn. When I try to draw it in Update() nothing is appearing on the screen but I still can see "The axes have been drawn in Update" showing up in the console. I tried to do it in OnPostRender() but it doesn't seem to be triggered, "The axes have been drawn" doesn't show up in the console.

What could I be doing wrong ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AxesManager : MonoBehaviour {

   private static readonly int DEFAULT_AXIS_LENGTH = 100;

   private Material _xMaterial;
   private Material _yMaterial;
   private Material _zMaterial;

   private Vector3 _origin;
   private int _length;


   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
       UpdateMaterials();
       _origin = GetAxesOrigin();
       _length = DEFAULT_AXIS_LENGTH;
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {
      //ClearAxes();
      //DrawAxes();
      //Debug.Log("The axes have been drawn in Update");
   }

   void OnPostRender()
   {
       DrawAxes();
       Debug.Log("The axes have been drawn");
   }

   private void DrawAxes()
   {
       //draw x axis
       GL.PushMatrix();
       GL.MultMatrix(transform.localToWorldMatrix);
       _xMaterial.SetPass(0);
       GL.LoadOrtho();
       GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
       GL.Color(Color.green);
       GL.Vertex(_origin);
       GL.Vertex(new Vector3(_length, 0, 0));
       GL.End();
       GL.PopMatrix();

       //draw y axis
       GL.PushMatrix();
       GL.MultMatrix(transform.localToWorldMatrix);
       _yMaterial.SetPass(0);
       GL.LoadOrtho();
       GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
       GL.Color(Color.red);
       GL.Vertex(_origin);
       GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0, _length, 0));
       GL.End();
       GL.PopMatrix();

       //draw z axis
       GL.PushMatrix();
       GL.MultMatrix(transform.localToWorldMatrix);
       _zMaterial.SetPass(0);
       GL.LoadOrtho();
       GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
       GL.Color(Color.blue);
       GL.Vertex(_origin);
       GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0, 0, _length));
       GL.End();
       GL.PopMatrix();

   }

   private void ClearAxes()
   {
       //clear the axes here
   }

   private Vector3 GetAxesOrigin()
   {
       return new Vector3(100,100,0);
   }

   private void UpdateMaterials()
   {
       _xMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "XAxisMaterial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
       _yMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "YAxisMaterial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
       _zMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "ZAxisMaterial", typeof(Material)) as Material;
   }
}
```

EDIT : After having attached the script to a camera (rendering the top layer), I can now see OnPostRender() being triggered, but nothing shows up and no errors. What could it be ?

Comment: `OnPostRender` is the place you want to call it. Make sure your script is attached to the camera and is enabled.

Comment: What object is this script attached to? `OnPostRender()` will only be called if attached to an active camera in the scene.

Comment: oh it is actually attached to an empty object, not one of the cameras, I will try this out

Comment: There's an asset on the store that already does this. Unless it doesn't do what you want, you should get it .

Comment: I added it as a component of a camera which is actually rendering things on the very top layer and now I can see OnPostRender() being triggered. However, I still can't see anything being drawn, without indicating any error in the console. What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: @ChuckSavage I looked out on the store but I didn't find such an asset